# tortoise merge confusion on updating the branch

Tags: merge, mercurial, tortoisesvn, branch, git-svn

I have a branch named A. I create another branch from A named as B. I work on the new branch B and push it. Later on I work on branch A and push it. Now, I switch back to branch B but I want it to update with the latest changes of branch A.

so should I merge from branch **A** to branch **B**, or branch **B** to branch **A**

Comment: Clear out your tags and clarify the question; is this SVN, Mercurial, or Git?

Comment: Your question has the answer -- `I want it (branch B) to update with the latest changes of branch A`.  If you want update branch B you should merge A into B.

Comment: When you merge, the branch you merge *to* becomes the branch the merge changeset is committed on. If you want to update B with the latest changes from A, it sounds like you want the merge changeset to be on branch B, and thus you should merge from A into B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a normal case, the result of the merge is usually unique, whether you go to one direction or the other. The branch destination, however, depends only on your interpretation of the branches.

For example, you should merge the development branches in the stable branch only when they are deemed ready, but the stable can go in development more often.